# Which usepackage for theorem and lemma?

Tags: environments, theorems

the proof environment works, but the theorem environment doesn't.
I don't know why this doesn't work:

[image]

When I put the red box in comment, it all works without any problem, but not sure why, as I can use the order `\begin{theorem}...\end{theorem}`

The code is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\usepackage[plainpages=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}

\oddsidemargin=0.in
\topmargin=-1.5cm
\textheight=23cm
\textwidth=16cm

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesubsection.\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesubsection.\arabic{equation}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\newcommand{\boxing}[1]{
\begin{center}
\framebox[\linewidth][c]{\parbox{15.5cm}{{#1}}}
\end{center}}

\begin{document}
\newpage
\begin{proof}
Test 1
\end{proof}

\begin{theorem}
Test 2
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) you have to define the theorem like constructions you need, try `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]` , the the manual for `amsthm` for details.

Comment: @daleif: (1)Thank you (2) I already use the package  $amsthm$ , but if I try to use your idea , I don't get an error, but it doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mostly theorems are not defined by default. As some prefer writing `thm` as the environment name, others prefer `theorem` as the environment name.

You can use

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
```

To create a new `theorem` environment, in this case its number will be dominated by the section number. (Note that this construction also create a new counter called `theorem`)

Often we'd like to have other theorem like constructions sharing the same counter, thus so we get Theorem 1.1, Lemma 1.2 etc.

This can be done using a slightly different syntax

```
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
```

where we here pass the name of the already made counter, thus we do not make a new counter, we'll just use the one we have.

For further details, see the manual for the `amsthm` package.

---

BTW: LaTeX provides `\newtheorem` out of the box, not packages needed. The `amsthm` package just extends it in a convenient way. See also the `thmtools` package for an alternative syntax for making theorem like constructions.